# LPC1769 CAN communication

Tags: can, lpc, lpcxpresso

I am learning CAN bus with [LPC1769](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1769_68_67_66_65_64_63.pdf) and the [LPCXpresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NXP_LPC#Development_boards) base board. I am in badly need of some demo code on CAN communication on the LPC1769 to know how it can be configured and works, but I can not find any.

Is there some website that can be recommended where I can find some (I have tried www.lpcware.com, but I did not find anything)?

Comment: Try with this site https://www.lpcware.com/content/device/lpc175x6x

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this http://support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/NXPDriverLibraries on my LPC1769 board but failed to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the links:

1.[MCB1700 Sample code](https://www.lpcware.com/content/nxpfile/mcb1700-sample-code-bundle-lpc17xx-peripherals-using-keils-mdk-arm)

2.Install free version of IAR. There are a lot free examples given by IAR for LPC1769.

3.Install free version of LPCXpresso IDE. There are a lot free examples given by LPCXpresso as well.